# how to close all postgres connections through app

Tags: java, postgresql, connection

I want to add restore functionality to my jsf app.

I need to restore the `sql` file, but my connections to PostgreSQL prevent me from doing that.

How can I close all connection to database in order to restore the `sql` file?

I am using a connection pool and I destroy all connections but PostgreSQL tell me there is a open session

```
/**
 * destroy postgresql connection pool
 */
public static void releasePostgresPool() {
    postgresConnectionPool.destroy();
}
```

Comment: Sounds like a bad design.  Connections should not be long lived.  can't scale this way.

Comment: thank you @duffymo , i have some scheduling on this app and they use connections, but i can destroy all connection using  `releasePostgresPool` function

Comment: You should pool connections and check them in and out like library books.  Use them in the narrowest scope possible and return them to the pool.

Answer (score 1):

You may close all postgresql connections from database side using this query:

```
select pg_terminate_backend(pid) from pg_stat_activity where pid <> pg_backend_pid();
```

not sure if it will be correct way for application (it should be able to reconnect after this).